A question about the diagonal of the powers of real, symmetric matrices
Let $A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$. Define $$\mathrm{diag}(A): M_{n\times n} \to M_{n \times 1} \text{ where } \mathrm{diag}(A) = \{a_{ii}\}_{i=1}^{n}$$ I have the following $\textbf{conjecture}$: Let $A,B$ be real symmetric. There exists a unique permutation matrix $\pi$ for all $k\geq 0$ such that $$\mathrm{diag}(A^k) = \pi~ \mathrm{diag}(B^k)$$ if and only if $$\mathrm{diag}(A^k) = \pi~ \mathrm{diag}(B^k) ~~~(\star)$$ for $0\leq k \leq n$.
$\textbf{My approach:}$ ($\implies$) follows by defintion. To show ($\impliedby$), let $\ell > n$. We can write the matrix $A^\ell $ as a linear combination of powers of $A$, using Cayley-Hamilton theorem: $$A^\ell = c_{n-1}A^{n-1} + \cdots + c_1 A + c_0 I_n $$ where $c_i$ are real coefficients. We need a small lemma before we go:
$\textbf{Lemma:}$ $$\mathrm{diag}: M_{n\times n} \to M_{n \times 1}$$ is a linear map.
Then it follows that $$\mathrm{diag} (A^\ell) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c_i \mathrm{diag}(A^i)$$ Similarly, we get that $$\mathrm{diag}(B^\ell) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} d_i \mathrm{diag}(B^i)$$ Using $(\star)$ we get that $$\mathrm{diag} (A^\ell) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c_i \mathrm{diag}(A^i) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c_i \pi(\mathrm{diag}(B^i)) = \pi(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c_i \mathrm{diag}(B^i)) $$ So it only remains to show that $$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c_i \mathrm{diag}(B^i) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} d_i \mathrm{diag}(B^i)$$ I don't immidiately see why\if this is true. Would appreciate some general advice or reference.

If the diagonals are equal up to a permutation, then also the traces are equal, but the traces are sums of powers of the eigenvalues, and since these are a (Newton) basis for the space of polynomials then you are proving that $A$ and $B$ are similar. As a consequence, they have the same characteristic polynomial and $c_i=d_i$

Probably you can prove more at this point. My conjecture is that for some permutation matrix $P$, you get $A=PBP^T$

Because $A,B$ are real symmetric, they are unitarily diagonalizable. That is, there exist unitaries $V,W$ such that $A=VDV^*$, $B=WEW^*$, with $D,E$ diagonal.
Because taking the diagonal is linear, you have $\def\diag{\operatorname{diag}}\diag p(A)=\diag p(B)$ for all polynomials $p$ of degree at most $n$. If we add over the diagonal, we get $\def\tr{\operatorname{Tr}}\tr(p(A))=\tr(p(B))$ for all polynomials $p$ of degree at most $n$.
As $p(A)=p(VDV^*)=Vp(D)V^*$ and $p(B)=Wp(E)W^*$, we have
$$\tag1
\tr(p(D))=\tr(p(E))
$$
for all polynomials $p$ of degree at most $n$. If $D_{11}$ does not appear in the diagonal of $E$, we can choose $p$ so that $p(D_{11})=1$, $p(D_{jj})=0$ for all $j$ such that $D_{jj}\ne D_{11}$, and $p(E_{kk})=0$ for all $k$. For such $p$ the left-hand-side of $(1)$ is nonzero, while the right-hand-side is zero. It follows that the diagonals of $D$ and $E$ have the same elements. This extends to the elements having the same multiplicities, for if $D_{jj}$ appears $r$ times on $D$ and it appears $s$ times on $E$, we can construct a polynomial $q(x)$ with $q(D_{jj})=1$ and $q=0$ on all the remaining entries of $D$ and $E$; then $(1)$ gives  $s=\tr(q(E))=\tr(q(D))=r$.
Thus the diagonal of $E$ is a permutation of the diagonal of $D$. That is, there exists a unitary permutation $U$ such that $E=UDU^*$. Then
$$
B=WEW^*=WUDU^*W^*=WUV^*AVU^*W^*=(WUV^*)A(WUV^*)^*.
$$
That is, $A$ and $B$ are unitarily equivalent: $B=ZAZ^*$ for a unitary $Z$. In particular, their characteristic polynomials $p_A$ and $p_B$ are equal. Your argument with Cayley-Hamilton shows that there exists a polynomial $q$ such that $(x^\ell-q)(A)=0$. Then $p_B=p_A$ divides $x^\ell-q$; thus $(x^\ell-q)(B)=0$. This shows that you can take $d_j=c_j$ in your argument.

I think you can prove $Z$ are permutation matrices

I don't think so. Consider $\def\diag{\operatorname{diag}}$ $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&1/2\1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad B=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&-1/2\-1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix}.$$ Then $B=ZAZ^*$ for a unitary $Z$ and $\diag(A^k)=\diag(B^k)$ for all $k$, but you cannot take $Z$ to be a permutation.

Also consider a traceless symmetric permutation matrix (involution without fixed points)-- it cannot be permutation similar to its negative since permutation matrices have non-negative components
